# Python regression analysis error

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression

I'm trying to run a regression analysis with the below mentioned code. I encounter ImportError: No module named statsmodels.api and No module named matplotlib.pyplot. Any suggestions will be appreciated to overcome this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats, integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.read_csv("F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DAT_OL\MASTRTAB.csv")
# define the data/predictors as the pre-set feature names
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

# Put the target (IMR) in another DataFrame
target = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["IMR"])

X = df["HH_LATR","COMM_TOILT","PWS"]
y = target["IMR"]

model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X) # make the predictions by the model

# Print out the statistics
model.summary()

plt.scatter(predictions, y, s=30, c='r', marker='+', zorder=10) #Plot graph
plt.xlabel("Independent variables")
plt.ylabel("Outcome variables")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you installed them?

Comment: Are you using Anaconda or `pip` or something else as a package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend that you install ANACONDA. This way the environment variables are set automatically and you don't need to worry about anything else. There are many useful packages (e.g. numpy, sympy, scipy) which are bundled with anaconda.

Moreover, based on personal experience I can tell you that using pip on windows and compiling from source (you need visual studio) is a pain in the neck sometimes. That's why ANACONDA has been conceived.

see : https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Hope this helps.